# How to fadeOut jquery Superfish on rollout ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, superfish

I am using query super fish and i would like to fadeout the menu on rollout. 
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing animations with superfish are not supported.  There may be a few hacks out there, but it appears that the official distribution does not support them.

Comment: do you have an example of hack ? i just would like to do a simple fadeout…

Comment: @rogaroga Here is the link to the potential hack:http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg34830.html.  Have not tried it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. the hack was not working for me… so i did my own menu script.

Answer (score 0):

There is still an active branch working on Superfish, called [Superfish Reloaded](https://github.com/bobbravo2/superfish-reloaded).
Looking at their code, an **animOut** is implemented, now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#menu1').superfish({
            delay: 1000,
            speedIn     : 300,
            speedOut    : 100,
            animIn: {marginTop: '10px','opacity':'show','height':'show'},
            animOut: {marginTop: '-10px', 'opacity':'hide','height':'hide'}
        });
        $('#default').superfish();  
    })
```